# Normal Prism + Geometric Optics

Tags: geometric-optics

I'm interested in finding such minimum angle of a prism, which ensures that all the rays pass through it, irrespective of the incident angle. Let's suppose the refractive index of the prism $\mu (= \frac{5}{4})$. Also, just for the sake of convenience, let's consider only such cases where the routine results for a normal prism work.

Here's what I did,
For all rays to come out, the angle of prism must atleast be equal to that value for which the incident light ray emerges out at grazing emergence.
Applying Snell's Law at the emerging ray, we get $\mu \sin(\theta) = 1 \\ \frac{5}{4} \sin(\theta)=1 \\ \theta=53^{\circ}$

Okay, now, at the incident side, let the angle of incidence be $i$. Applying Snell's Law,
$\sin(i)=\mu\sin(r_1)$
For the extremities, let's have $i=\frac{\pi}{2},$ So,
$\\ \mu\sin(r_1)=1\\ \sin(r_1)=\frac{1}{\mu}\\\sin(r_1)=\frac{4}{5}\\\implies r_1=53^\circ$

Also, by simple geometry, we have the result, $\theta+r_1 = A$, the angle of prism. So, we finally get $A\geq 53^\circ + 53^\circ \\ A\geq 106^\circ$.

> But I'm stuck because I don't think this result I got is correct. Am I missing something? Your comments and discuss is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybee you sketch your prism with 106° than you will see that most rays do not reach the other side, but the base of the prism.

Comment: @trula True.. But it brings me back to my question, how do I solve it? 

Comment: Take 0° and it works. so look if it still works for 1° or 10°- best with a sketch first.